Can't see NVMe drive in WinPE
I have a new (overstock) Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ITL05 laptop. I'm trying to boot into WinPE to do some pre-deployment prep work. When I do, WinPE boots just fine, but I am unable to access the internal nvme drive. It doesn't even show when I run the list disk command in diskpart.
Initial research indicates this is a problem with Intel's RST driver. However, there are no options in the BIOS/UEFI to set for AHCI or similar modes. Instead, the guidance suggests I need to use DISM to inject the Rapid Storage Technology driver into the WinPE boot.wim file before running MakeWinPEMedia.
I've done this more than half a dozen times now with different drivers, including both the Windows 10 and Windows 11 options for this specific model on the Lenovo support site. I allowed the machine to boot the default Windows installation and matched the driver version I saw there. Intel's download site also has drivers for both 10 & 11th Gen and 11 to 13th Gen platforms, and I tried the latest version of both (since they both match my 11th Gen CPU).
None of these drivers work. The internal drive never appears in diskpart, and I'm burning too much time on this. I've used the same WinPE environment with many other computers, including other similar IdeaPad models (both older and newer).
What am I missing?

Unless you have installed Windows while in RAID mode (or Intel RST) is turned on this problem has nothing to do with Intel RST. Due to the fact you have a laptop it's unlikely Windows is installed in RAID mode.

@Ramhound Any other reasons the disk might not show up in WinPE?
